# 16.04: Why is "Cheese" installed by default?

Tags: 16.04, webcam, default-programs, cheese

Cheese can activate your webcam automatically.

So far, it appears it can only store locally.  WireShark does not show comms.

But the QUESTION IS;  Why is Cheese a default program installation>?

Comment: Because many people like to use their webcam on their pc?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Please don't post answer in comments ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because on a fresh installation one may want to check that the webcam works. Other than that it's a tool to provide functionality to the webcam. Meaning; without cheese how can you use your webcam to take local photos?

It's a very nice open-source program that's about a few megabytes in size so why not include it in the Ubuntu iso?